# How to calculate [Math.pow] column specific in all rows from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to calculate power of number(Math.pow) for specific columns.
And this my code :

```
public void showData()
    {
       //query code//
       int i = 0;
       int[] sum = new int[101];
       for (i = 1; i < 101; i++)
       {
           double Avg;
           int indexOfcolumn;
           sum[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(BIN" + i.ToString() + ")", string.Empty));
           if (sum[i] == 0)
           {
               dt.Columns.Remove("BIN" + i.ToString() + "");
           }
           else{
               dt.Columns.Add("%BIN" + i.ToString() + "", typeof(double), "(BIN" + i.ToString() + " / [In System])*100 ");
               indexOfcolumn = dt.Columns.IndexOf("%BIN" + i.ToString() + "");
               if (i == 1)
               {
                    double value = 0;
                    double pow = 0;
                    for (int p = 0; p < dt.Rows.Count - 1; p++)
                    {
                        int d = dt.Columns.IndexOf("_100BIN1");
                        value = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[p][indexOfcolumn].ToString());
                        pow = Math.Pow(value,-0.5);   
                    }
                    dt.Columns.Add("test", typeof(double), pow.ToString());         
               }
          }
     }
```

The problem from my code :

```
double value = 0;
double pow = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < dt.Rows.Count - 1; p++)
{
   int d = dt.Columns.IndexOf("_100BIN1");
   value = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[p][indexOfcolumn].ToString());
   pow = Math.Pow(value,-0.5);   
}
dt.Columns.Add("test", typeof(double), pow.ToString());
```

In column name "test" get value from loop.it display in dataGridView only one value

update my code:

```
dt.Columns.Add("test", typeof(double));
dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged);
```

And this:

```
private static void TableRowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
   e.Row.Table.RowChanged -= new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged);
   e.Row["test"] = Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row["_100BIN1"]),Convert.ToInt32(-0.5));
   e.Row.Table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Column.Expression has some limitations. But you could achieve this using var making use of RowChanged Event. For Example,

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("One");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Two");
dataTable.Columns.Add("Pow");//
dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged);
```

Where TableRowChanged is defined as

```
private static void TableRowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Table.RowChanged -= new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged);
    e.Row["Pow"]= Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row["One"]),Convert.ToInt32(e.Row["Two"]));
    e.Row.Table.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged);
}
```

Do ensure RowChanged Event is unsubscribed before the calculation and added back again as seen in the example above.

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Xj5J8)

Comment: I do as you suggest.But results not display when i set to display in dataGridView.

Comment: Do you subscribe to the event before or after filling the datatable ?

Comment: No,I don't.Can you give me some advice?

Comment: I meant, did you do dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(TableRowChanged); This needs to be done before you add any rows to the dataTable.Could you share your updated code ?